# How do you mock callback parameters, e.g., for chrome.storage.local.get(), in plain JavaScript (ES6)?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, google-chrome-extension, mocking

chrome.storage is a handy api for storing data for Chrome Extensions: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

The get() method described there has a required callback param.

This can be used like so:

```
function go(storage) { // chrome.storage.local
  storage.get(MY_CONST, (result) => {
    if (!result[MY_CONST]) {
      foo();
    }
  });
}
```

`storage` is passed in as a variable so that tests can be more flexible.

However, **how do you mock the value of `result` in tests, with plain ES6 JS? Is that possible?**

For example, in a test file, you might make a fake storage class and pass that in when you call `go()`:

```
class FakeStorage {
  constructor() {
    this.data = {};
  }
  set(keyValuePair) {
    this.data = keyValuePair;
  }
  get(key, callback) {
    callback(); // how do you force a parameter in the callback?
  }
}
```

I can think of a way to test by spying on chrome.storage.local, but I would like to know if I can mock with plain JS instead, because then, the whole point of abstracting `storage` to be a parameter for `go()` is pointless.
(Moreover, it's better to mock if you can, since it just forces you to test the core functionality; spying can become verbose.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `callback(this.data);` or `callback({[key]: 'foo'});` ?

Comment: Yes that works - unclear why this didn't occur to me. Thanks!